# Create a density plot of vertical lines in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, density-plot, horizontal-line

I have a bunch of data cotaining coordinate intervals within one large region, which i want to plot and then create a density plot showing where in the region there are more interval lines than others.

As a very basic example i've just plotted some horizontal lines for a given interval. I cant really find any good examples of how to create a better plot of intervals. I've looked into seaborn, but im not entirely sure about it. So here i've just created a basic example of what i am trying to do.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = np.linspace(1, 30,100)
x2 = np.linspace(10,40,100)
x3 = np.linspace(2,50,100)
x4 = np.linspace(40,60,100)
x5 = np.linspace(30,78,100)
x6 = np.linspace(82,99,100)
x7 = np.linspace(66,85,100)
x = [x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7]
y = np.linspace(1,len(x),len(x))
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(len(x)):
    ax.hlines(y[i], xmin=x[i][0], xmax=x[i][-1], linewidth=1)
plt.xlim(-5,105)
plt.show()
```

[image]

And then I would like to create a density plot of the number of intervals overlapping. Could anyone have any suggestions on how to proceed with this?

Thans for your help and suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do what you want:

```
def count(xi):
    samples = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)
    return (xi[0] < samples) & (samples <= xi[-1])

is_in_range = np.apply_along_axis(count, arr=x, axis=1)
density = np.sum(is_in_range, axis=0)
```

The general idea is to make some output `linspace`, then check to see if those coordinates are in the ranges in the array `x` — that's what the function `count` does. Then `apply_along_axis` runs this function on every row (i.e. every 1D array) in your array `x`.

Here's what I get when I plot `density`:

[image: The result of the density counting]

You might want to adjust the `<=` and `<` signs in the `count` function to handle the edges as you like.

If your actual data have a different format, or if there are multiple intervals in one array, you will need to adjust this.